# What would happen if the wavelength of light gets doubled?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, material-science, wavelength

As I was researching about how wifi works, I saw that wireless information exchange happens by using electro magnetic waves.

Also, the shorter the electro magnetic waves are, the less they can pass a material (like a wall). So senders with 5 GHz are not able to send as good as senders with 2.4 GHz through a wall.

And light is also an electro magnetic wave, right?
So what would happen if the wavelength of it got doubled? or tripled?

Would light then be able to "go through a wall"?

Comment: What would happen to what? The question isn't clear.

Comment: X- and gamma rays can pass matter more easily than light and have way shorter wavelength. The assumption about shorter -> less penetrability is wrong.

Comment: @Jasper ok, well....

Comment: @Jasper, when light travells at the speed of light (yeah), aren't the things that oscillate (I don't know what they are - protons?) to make the wave even faster?

Answer (score 0):

The [electromagnetic spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum) is a continuum.

Look at the wavelengths in the table, when you double or triple you will end up on a different definition .Light is visual definition, and doubling wavelengths will take you to infrared, where all the heat is related and so not useful for carrying information as matter absorbs it fast. To be able to pass through walls you need huge factors to bring you to the giga herz region.